# Is it possible to connect iPhones through NAT traversal techniques over 3G for peer 2 peer gaming

Tags: iphone, networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

Is it possible to connect an iPhone to another iPhone or any other network client talking that game's protocol.

I was thinking that I could use the same [NAT Traversal technique](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/) used in the XBox 360 to host games on users XBox's through Firewalls.

For NAT traversal to work effectively I'd have to have a central server that would allow clients to "broadcast" that they were hosting so that another client could initiate the NAT connection. In the link provided this is called relaying.

Is there any inherent limitation of the US AT&T 3G network that will block the NAT traversal techniques (would you be limited to wifi firewall NAT traversal)?

NAT Traversal Projects:
 - [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/) - providing NAT traversal functionalities by using standard based protocols such as STUN, TURN, and ICE.
 - [Freecast using Apache MINA Java network library for NAT Traversal](http://www.nabble.com/Another-MINA-use-case:-freecast.org-td7521483.html)

Comment: Not sure how this is programming-related.

Comment: because it involves implementing software-level workarounds to network limitations.

Comment: NAT Traversal techniques are a socket programming concept where the server, behind a firewall through various socket connection techniques called "hole punching" is able to trick a firewall into directing network traffic to that open port allowing servers to host without opening a port on the firewall (read the "Establishing Peer-to-Peer Sessions" to get details on the socket programming concepts for NAT traveral). 

I also included a code sample link about NAT traversal (seriously it's very programming related).

Comment: I stand corrected. It appeared very 'network adminy' at first. :)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

iPhone OS 3.0 will have an API for multiplayer gaming and connectivity with over devices in your immediate area,

> "You can find other iPhones and iPod Touches in a given area that are playing the same game as you; Forstall gives the example of two kids in the back of a car. iPhone 3.0 will automatically discover other applications over Bluetooth, and there's no pairing. "Completely seamless," he promises. Bonjour is the back-end technology behind this, and it's not just for games"

Sources: [CNET Live Blog](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-10197216-37.html), and the  [Apple Special Event Quicktime Video](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/qtv/preview-iphone-os/) It's about 20 minutes into the presentation.

If you are going for something more than playing with nearby devices, you will probably run into problems with bandwidth caps on the 3G network as well as latency issues depending on where users are located. Boonies with very sporadic 3G coverage vs. downtown major city USA with multiple cell towers concentrated in a small area. You may also run into a problem with AT&T depending on how much data the game is sending and receiving from the phone over the 3G network since multiplayer games require the players and the server (even if it's a player acting as one) to send information back and forth constantly. Interesting idea though!

Comment: I'm very excited about the new iPhone OS 3.0 GameKit bluetooth features.

But in cases where you are on WiFi where you could conceivably play some low-latency, high-bandwidth type multiplayer games with people across the world. 

It'd be cool to be able to host a game server from my phone and allow users to connect to it and play over the internet. To support this you need a way to get through normal wifi firewalls (like XBox Live does), that's why I was wondering if anyone has implemented NAT traversal on the iphone.

Also it'd be interesting to know if this is possible on the 3G network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Eyeball Networks has released a SDK for [iPhone NAT Traversal](http://www.voipforiphone.net/iphone-nat-traversal.htm)

Comment: Very interesting! Please tell me what you mean by 'released', I can't find any download or purchase links.

Answer (score 1):

AT&T appear to use a randomized symmetric NAT - this means traversal is not possible between 2 iphones on their network without a relay server. What I don't know is if iPhones on AT&T can reach each other directly using their private addresses if they are on the same part of AT&T's network, or if there is some firewall. Last time I checked TMobile used a port restricted cone NAT, so traversal is possible between iPhones on TMobile, but not from TMobile to AT&T.

Answer (score 0):

3G is a big problem. If you'd like to establish UDP connections with other players over 3G, you might want to try this technique:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IimJ20gG0SY2NvaE4wRVVMbG8/view?usp=sharing